# Formulating a polynomial with integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials

**Question**

Find the equation of a polynomial with **integer coefficients** that has a double zero at $x=-\frac{2}{3}$, a single zero at $x=(1-2\sqrt{3})$, and goes through $(-1,-24)$.

**Attempt**

I have tried to formulate the equation with the information given. My initial thought is to make sure that all the coefficients are integers. So, rather than having $(x+\frac{2}{3})$ as one of the factors, I have $(3x+2)^2$ to make the coefficient an integer. Hence, this leads to

$$y=a(3x+2)^2(x-1+2\sqrt{3})$$

When I substitute $x=-1$ and $y=-24$ into the above, it yields,

$$a=\frac{-24}{-2+2\sqrt{3}}$$

which when multiplied by the conjugate of the denominator will yield $(-6-6\sqrt{3})$.

So my equation now becomes

$$y=(-6-6\sqrt{3})(3x+2)^2(x-1+2\sqrt{3})$$

But no matter how I tried further, there is no way I can achieve an **integer** coefficient of $x$.

May I know is my approach correct? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: The polynomial you are looking for is allowed to have zeros other than the ones mentioned explicitly in the question. Can you think of any nice polynomial (e.g. a quadratic) that has $1-2\sqrt{3}$ as a root?

Comment: If a polynomial with rational coefficients has the irrational root $a+i\sqrt{b}$, it has and the conjugate root $a-i\sqrt{b}$, so it can't have only one irrational root.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thank you very much. I got it now. But the question should then also mention there is another root at $1+2\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @Vasile But the roots given is not a complex number. Does the same apply to real roots?

Comment: @IM_LOST: Errata If a polynomial with rational coefficients has the irrational root a+√b, it has and the conjugate root a−√b, so it can't have only one irrational root. Sorry for the mistake!